# How to force web to support only if user is last chrome user?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my page will support only latest chrome user.
I Can detect the browser and version with that:

```
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var is_chrome = !!window.chrome;
    var ver = parseInt(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)\./)[1], 10);
</script>
</body>
```

But how can I stop my support for all page?

Comment: Define support please

Comment: dont... instead test for whatever experimental feature you are using.

Comment: This is bad practice, and an user-agent can be spoofed easily. Look [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/56327/42730) for better solutions.

Comment: If you don't want your page to appear, check the browser type & version. If the browser isn't what you want, just redirect to a different page in your site. (That other page could tell the user what browser they need to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, ***this is a really bad thing to do for anything serious***, but to answer your question... you could hide your content via CSS, and show it via JavaScript if your detect "latest Chrome". Note that this does not "force" anything and is easily broken.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content {display:none}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="warning">
            Error: Must use latest Chrome
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Welcome latest Chrome user! This is my page.
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var is_latest_chrome = [whatever];
            if (is_latest_chrome) {
                document.getElementById("warning").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("content").style.display="block";               
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/PP6tD/)**</kbd>

```
  var version = navigator.userAgent.substr(navigator.userAgent.lastIndexOf('Chrome/') + 7, 2);

  if(version == 34) {
     console.log(version);
  }
```